# Is there any tool like firebug which can save css file while editing in firebug

Tags: firefox-addon, firebug

I want to know that is there any tool in which when we change css in firebug,that get get's automatically get's saved to the css file

i have searched a lot ... and found few add-ons but didn't found out what exactly what i want

if anyone can pass me a link for that add-on it will be great
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be be able to persist changes with google chrome's developer tools.  See this article for instructions:  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/elements-styles#persist

Comment: thanx i'll try this tommarow and accept your answer after that.. and a plus one..thanks for showing interest

Comment: You might also look at this:  http://acpote.com/2012/03/29/save-css-firebug-css-updater/